# Swift 3 and XCode 8: TextField bug in UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

It seems there's a bug on Swift 3 and XCode 8, the `UIBezierPath`

```
    let myBounds = textField.bounds

    let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: myBounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))

    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.frame = myBounds
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath

    self.textField.layer.mask = maskLayer

    let frameLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    frameLayer.frame = myBounds
    frameLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
    frameLayer.strokeColor = UIColor(hexString: "#59a646").cgColor
    frameLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    frameLayer.lineWidth = 1*2;
    self.textField.layer.addSublayer(frameLayer)
```

**It used to produce similar to this**

[image]

**But now**

[image]

Any work-arounds?

Comment: Instead of stating "It's producing incorrect results", tell us what it's actually doing and what you think it should be doing. Perhaps include a screen capture.

Comment: Updated my question, @maddy thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely to be a bug, and more likely to be changed behaviour that your code no longer works with.

It sounds very similar to how cornerRadius "no longer works" because the view's size is now 1000x1000 at the time you set it. This can be fixed by calling the view's `layoutIfNeeded()` before you start styling. So first, I would try the same solution.

Nevertheless, it looks like there is a white rectangle obscuring part of your bezier path. Try setting the background to a different colour to confirm. Could it be that you're setting the `cornerRadius` on that view, and it's no longer working as expected?

Alternatively, try moving all the code to the `viewDidAppear` stage. This is probably not a permanent solution as you will see everything paint, but it might help understand what is going on.

Comment: I actually tried in a UIView instead of UITextField and it's working fine, giving me correct results. And I also checked some Github codes and looks my assumption is correct.